# Why does the aileron on this jetliner swing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, ailerons

[image: Inboard aileron of a jetliner]

The picture I took [here](https://youtu.be/Rtl5WUA5ATE?t=139) is left wing of a jetliner and it shows how the flap works during take off and landing.

In that video is the inboard aileron, and it shows that the inboard aileron is not firmly controlled. It is like it is swinging up and down.

My question is, why does it look like it swings? Is it intended to be so? If yes, why?

Comment: All I see is the aileron being actuated as the pilot (or autopilot) flies the approach.

Comment: @Jim, in 4:04, it is still swing even just exactly before touch the ground, which in that situation should no more rolling control.

Comment: Why not? The pilot flies the aircraft all the way onto the ground and beyond.

Comment: Also, at 4:04 the plane is still in the air.  It doesn’t land until closer to 4:16.

Comment: If you look carefully, you can also see the ailerons swing up and down in a seemingly "unfirmly controlled" manner.

Comment: For an example of the kinds of control inputs made during a landing see this video: https://youtu.be/JhUcNh5_UPE

Comment: Related: [How does the particular piece of flap behind an engine on a B777 work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8825/14897) and [Why do flaperons 'move down then up' on takeoff roll on a 787?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38230/14897)

Comment: @Jim, sorry for my mistake. It was not 4:04, but 4:14, less than a second before it touch the ground. So, good to see in 0.54, just a second after it left the gound.

Comment: @Jim, see this [B747-8 landing](https://youtu.be/iymxEKpmiIU?t=138). Even after it touch the ground, it is still swing.

Comment: @AirCraftLover - The nose is still in the air - the pilot is still flying. Once the nose comes down the pilot puts out the spoilers.   And besides that clearly looks controlled not flapping around in the wind, right?

Comment: See this [Q&A](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22678/14897): *Complete your rollout with the **appropriate crosswind aileron deflection...*** → Roll input is **not** stopped after touchdown. (Though that's not part of the Q as written, and now it's too late to edit it.)

Comment: @ymb1, thank you for your link, especially the first link. I read it so I late to reply your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flaperon points downwards to function as a flap, and moves up/down to induce rolling moments, which may be necessary to keep the wings horizontal when for instance wind gusts or turbulence are attempting to roll the plane.

So what you see is the roll control to maintain level flight, the outboard ailerons move together with the corresponding flaperons at lower airspeeds, which can be seen in the video as well.

Comment: First, is its official name flaperon? I searched over the net before I posted this, I got [here] (https://history.nasa.gov/SP-367/chapt2.htm) that its name is inboard aileron. Sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: If we see in 0:54, it began to "swings", just one or two second after it left the ground. Is rolling performed so immediately after it left the ground?

Comment: Maybe it is good to see 0:54 just a second after it left the ground it is already "swings", and 4:14, less than a second before it touch the ground it is still "swings".

Comment: @AirCraftLover  A flaperon is an aileron whose "neutral" position is lowered below the normal chord line for low speed flight to provide double duty for roll control and additional lift, so it's accurate to call it a flaperon.  They are also called drooping ailerons.  But as far as I know, Boeing just calls them inboard ailerons whether they droop with the flaps or not, although in that case flaperon is a more accurate term.

Comment: The movement of the ailerons in landing is to create rolling moments, which compensate for what the side wind gusts are trying to do: roll the aeroplane. The rapid movements are to keep the wings level. All movement is the result of forces (moments when talking about rotations), the ailerons provide rapidly changing opposing moments for whatever the wind is trying to do.

Comment: @JohnK, thank you for your explanation. But there is one question from your explanation: *It is used for **low speed** flight to provide double duty for roll control and additional lift* control. I **bold** the **low speed** as I read [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-does-the-particular-piece-of-flap-behind-an-engine-on-a-b777-work) there is mentioned that flaperon is used for high speed control, opposite to your explanation.

Comment: @Koyovis, thank you for your supplement comment. I now understand it that it is intended to be so, it is in control.

Comment: @AirCraftLover  They are used for high speed roll control when fully up but moving differentially.  Low speed control when drooped and moving differentially.  They are used as ailerons in all flight regimes, whereas the outboard ailerons may be idled at high speeds.  It's just that when flaps come out, they still work as ailerons, but also droop with the flaps.

Comment: @JohnK, many thanks. Now I understand.